# Node.js NPM Google Search Result Returning [ Object object ] as result

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
    gSearch: function(message){
        googleSearch.build({
        q: message                                    
        }, 
        function(error, response) 
        {                     
        console.log(response);
        chain.send('/me ' + response);
        });
    },
```

Returns [ Object object ] as the result

This is not for HTML, its a bot meant for an IRC type chat. You send a request like !g "search term" then it is supposed to send back the search result to the chat. Made with node.js

Comment: You've clearly stated what happens, but not your question or problem.

Comment: How do I get it to return a search result instead of [Object object] it says my search term is [Object]

Comment: I am sorry, new at this.

Comment: You're getting back an object because there are many fields in the response. Pick out the ones you want and use those.

Comment: I want a proper Google search result.

Comment: Ok thank you so it would be something along the lines of response.url

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like that:

`gSearch: function(message){
        googleSearch.build({
        q: message

        }, 
        function(error, response) 
        {

        console.log(response);
        chain.send('/me', JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    },`

Answer (score 0):

`[Object object]` is the serialization of a javascript object.

You may want to [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```